# How to check `if` statement from database column like '$a > $b'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to check `if` statement from database column like `$a > $b` or `$a == $b` or `$a != $b` or `$a < $b`

I got data from database in `$row['condition']`
    `$row['condition'] = '$a  == $b';`
or 
$row['condition'] = '100  == 10';

in if statement I want to check

```
if($row['condition']){
   echo 'true';
}else{
   echo  'false';
}
```

I want to output

```
false
```

Comment: That is very insecure. But read http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php  in your case just `if(eval($row['condition'])){`

Answer (score 1):

A way to do so is using [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function. But as the manual says, this is **very dangerous**:

> **Caution**:
>   The **eval()** language construct is *very dangerous* because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. *Its use thus is discouraged*. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention *not to pass any user provided data* into it without properly validating it beforehand.<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)</sup>

That said, this code can be used:

```
$row['condition'] = '$a == $b';
$a=10;
$b=20;

// Evaluate the condition using "return your_condition;"
if (eval( 'return ' . $row['condition'] . ';' ))
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```

Test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/beb4be22addf67d5ab5acfdf3cd3cbeaa58d2885).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php</sub>